# Interoperability for rollup: Should the bridge (for early withdrawals) deploys rollup nodes to verify the commitments of each rollup?

Tags: node, smart-rollup, rollup

As far as I understand, there are bridges on ETH to enable early withdrawals from ORUs and transfer to other rollups.

Since running multiple rollup nodes for each rollup is ideal for user's funds safety (see here [How should rollup deployers incentivise others to deploy a rollup node to ensure everyone's funds are safe?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/5860/how-should-rollup-deployers-incentivise-others-to-deploy-a-rollup-node-to-ensure)), will this Tezos bridge, that a team will eventually develop, runs every rollup node (so at least there will be 2 rollups nodes per rollup integrated by the bridge) to check commitments?

Answer (score 1):

You have no incentive to operate the rollup. There is only 1 operator node at a time, except if you think the current operator is cheating, otherwise one will just be slash. Having several operators "ready" but not commiting can be a way to manage failover, for exemple when one stop to commit, then another start, stake and make the rollup progress.

Most will secure the rollup by running an accuser.

If you run this bridge you will likely run an accuser node on each integrated rollup and also have a scoring on every rollup to adapt fees and collateral.